# openldap add mail attribute to users

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to add 'mail' attribute to users on my openldap server but somehow it fails. 
I tried using ldapmodify but I get this:

```
ldap_modify: Object class violation (65)
additional info: attribute 'mail' not allowed
```

Here's how my schema looks like:

```
# LDIF Export for ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com
# Server:  (ldap.mydomain.com)
# Search Scope: sub
# Search Filter: (objectClass=*)
# Total Entries: 63

version: 1

# Entry 1: ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com
dn: ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: users

# Entry 2: uid=tom.hanks,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com
dn: uid=tom.hanks,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com
cn: tom.hanks
description: User account
gecos: tom.hanks
gidnumber: 100
homedirectory: /home/tom.hanks
loginshell: /bin/bash
objectclass: account
objectclass: posixAccount
uid: tom.hanks
uidnumber: 1005
userpassword: blahblah
```

Comment: Hi. I've managed to solve it by adding a new objectClass to all users: extensibleObject which contains the "email" attribute. Thanks.

Comment: try to add objectClass inetOrgPerson

Comment: You should add `iNetOrgPerson` and not the `entensibleObject`. Extensible Object will literally allow you to add any attribute to a directory entry that has it. If you want your objects to be able to have any attribute added to them, even made up ones, then by all means use `extensibleObject`.

Answer (score 9):

Include `objectclass: iNetOrgPerson` to add the `mail` attribute.

Comment: objectclass:iNetOrgPerson and objectclass: account can not be ussed at the same time; you'd need to remove the objectclass: account (and just leave objectclass: posixAccount, if you do not necessarily need objectclass: account)

Answer (score 0):

In order to give the user the Attribute mail you first have to add the mail attribute to the user's olcObjectClasses.

This can be done by a modification via an ldif like this:

```
dn: cn={12345}someName,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: {1}
-
add: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: {1}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.12344556.1.1.1 NAME 'yourObjectClassEGAccount' DESC 'some description' SUP inetOrgPerson STRUCTURAL MUST ( requiredparam1 $ requiredParam2 $ reqParam3 ) MAY ( optionalParam1 $ optionalParam2 ) ) )
-
```

See the documentation for ldapmodify for details: [Oracle ldapmodify Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19693-01/819-0995/6n3cq3apv/index.html#bcacw)

The modification is then given to ldap via the following command (command line):

```
sudo ldapmodify -f filename.ldif
```

make sure to read the documentation on whether you need further parameters like eg. -h for hostname or -Y for a proxyDN: [lmodify Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19199-01/816-6400-10/lmodify.html)